# How to use an sqlite3 connection in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I created the following `WebApp.test()` to test concurrent accesses to the database, to simulate a browser that executes some queries while a background task is updating the database.

The background task crashes when a new query that uses the same connection is executed. What am I doing wrong?

```
@cherrypy.expose
def test(self, x=''):

    if x == 'connect':
        WebApp.con = sqlite3.connect('db', check_same_thread=False)
        return 'connected'

    if x == 'insert':
        with WebApp.con: 
            cur = WebApp.con.cursor()
            cur.execute('drop table if exists x')
            cur.execute('create table x(x)')
            for i in range(10000):
                cur.execute('insert into x values (%s)' % i)
                WebApp.con.commit()
        return 'Inserted %s rows' % i

    if x == 'query': 
        with WebApp.con: 
            cur = WebApp.con.cursor()
            cur.execute('select * from x where x < 20')
            data = cur.fetchall()
        return 'result: %s' % data
```

I navigate to the following 3 pages in sequence, waiting just a few seconds between each one:

```
test?x=connect
test?x=insert
test?x=query
```

The first one creates the connection.

The second one starts a very long cycle that simulates a background job that will run for a few minutes on the server.

The third one makes a simple query.

When I navigate to the third page, the result of the query is returned as expected, but the cycle that is still running is interrupted with the following error:

```
    WebApp.con.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: cannot commit - no transaction is active
```

Comment: I've had a similar problem before and worked around it by creating one new sqlite connection per process/thread. There may be a better solution, but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I came to the following conclusions:

It is not possible to use the same connection in different threads at the same time. The two threads would share the same transaction, the same cursor, and other resources.

It is possible to use the same connection in different threads (not at the same time). For example [SqlAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html) uses a connection pool.

In simple web application (like mine) it is OK to create one connection at each call, with very little overhead.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you're using the connection object as a context manager in each case.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) mention that the connection will be committed or rolled back at the end.  You're explicitly committing it anyway (pretty much negating any benefit of using the context manager to start with).

So your third query commits the connection, which causes issues with your `insert` script, since the connection has now been committed.  (...or maybe it's even the explicit commits you're doing in your 10000 iteration loop)

Sqlite also [mentions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#multithreading) that you cannot share connections and cursors between threads.  I think you'll want to use a new connection each time.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) on the `connect` method:
*"When a database is accessed by multiple connections, and one of the processes modifies the database, the SQLite database is locked until that transaction is committed. The timeout parameter specifies how long the connection should wait for the lock to go away until raising an exception. The default for the timeout parameter is 5.0 (five seconds)."*